# Why i got error in reportview

Tags: java

```
private void searchBActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        ReportView r = new ReportView("C:\\Users\\Paul Nigel\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\DailyRecordManagement\\DailyRecordManagement\\src\\JasperReport\\report1.jasper");

    }
```

[image]

Comment: what error? exception? stacktrace?

Comment: @sharonbn It is a compile error. There is no stacktrace.

Comment: please edit the title to reflect that. did you import the package of ReportView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot file symbol

This is a compilation error, and in your case the symbol is *"ReportView"* which is a class.

This essentially means that:

1) You did not import this package in your code

2) You do not have the necessary jar, which contains this Class, on your class path/build path.

On a side note, did you intend to use the GWT *ReportViewer* class instead?

Comment: problem solve but got an error again 

here is the code: import net.sf.ReportView.view.ReportView;

Comment: where do i find the ReportView jar i already add the far file Jasper report

Comment: it looks like ReportView is a custom Class specific to your project. Please search for such class in project (should be easy in IDE)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you never import the class `ReportView` and/or you miss to add the jar file which the class contains.

Comment: @Nigel You also have imported the class? import ...ReportView in the header of your class?